# jquery select all checkboxes that share same tr id

Tags: jquery

I am working on some jquery that will check html checkboxes that share the same  ID

```
<span class="idclass"><input type="checkbox" class="idleft" name="selectALL" value="WLEVEL04"> Select All </span>


<td class="left"><input type="checkbox" name="unchecked[]" value="499703"></td>
<td class="left"><input type="checkbox" name="unchecked[]" value="855155"></td>
<td class="left"><input type="checkbox" name="unchecked[]" value="234203"></td>
<td class="left"><input type="checkbox" name="unchecked[]" value="489741"></td>
```

here is my jquery

```
    $(".idleft").live('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $(this).attr('tr').val(id).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
        });
```

Comment: ID's should be unique...also, `.live` is no longer used (assuming you're on the latest version of jQuery)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `$(this).attr('tr')` ?? What you are trying here ?

Comment: You don't even have any `tr`s in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe something like this is what you're looking for:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/3GkT3/

jQ:

```
$(".idleft").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("input[name^='unchecked']").each(function() {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        });
    } else {
        $("input[name^='unchecked']").each(function() {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var self = this,
        checked = self.checked,
        elClass = self.className.replace('id','');
    $('td.' + elClass).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',checked);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g8Huy/).

This works (and is [easily scalable](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g8Huy/1/)) if the checkbox has a single class-name (in this case `idleft`) *and* that class-name, minus the `id` portion, is the same as the class-name of the `td` elements.

It is, however, easier to use an `id` (rather than potentially have to filter through a list of potential class-names, and avoiding the `replace()` method), given the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="idclass"><input type="checkbox" id="left" class="idleft" name="selectALL" value="WLEVEL04" />Select All</span></td>
            <td class="left"><input type="checkbox" name="unchecked[]" value="499703" /></td>
            <td class="left"><input type="checkbox" name="unchecked[]" value="855155" /></td>
            <td class="left"><input type="checkbox" name="unchecked[]" value="234203" /></td>
            <td class="left"><input type="checkbox" name="unchecked[]" value="489741" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="idclass"><input type="checkbox" id="different" class="iddifferent" name="selectALL" value="WLEVEL04" />Select All</span></td>
            <td class="different"><input type="checkbox" name="differentName[]" value="499703" /></td>
            <td class="different"><input type="checkbox" name="differentName[]" value="855155" /></td>
            <td class="different"><input type="checkbox" name="differentName[]" value="234203" /></td>
            <td class="different"><input type="checkbox" name="differentName[]" value="489741" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With the following (only marginally-amended) jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var self = this,
        checked = self.checked,
        elClass = self.id;
    $('td.' + elClass).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',checked);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g8Huy/2/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).